# Html5 header inside a div

Tags: html

I have a modal popup which is wrapped inside a `DIV`.
The modal is extensive enough to have a `H1`, a `body(DIV)` and a `FOOTER`.

Is it correct to use `HEADER` and `FOOTER` elements in this way?

Answer (score 2):

See [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-header-element):

> The header element represents introductory content for its nearest ancestor sectioning content or sectioning root element

(Footer is defined with similar language to header.)

A div is not a sectioning element, so no, it isn't correct to use a header or footer element in that way. You would be defining a header and footer for (presumably) the body element, not your div.

If you replaced the div with a suitable sectioning element, then it might be appropriate.